# SQL Server : update a table with single row and about 20 columns is timing out. Any insights?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to update a table with a single row and has 24 columns on it. The query is very simple and is timing out.

```
UPDATE [settings] 
SET enable_login = 1
```

The table has one index, one trigger and couple of statistics enabled on it.

Any insights would help?

Comment: What is done in the trigger?

Comment: Check your Trigger. Possible disable your trigger and try to update the column and check.

Comment: @Rubik The trigger just executes a stored procedure based on a column value in the table.

Comment: @Selva TS. I deleted the trigger and tried the update query. But its still the same.

Comment: Also this particular table is constantly queried. Does that impact anything?

Comment: Could you check if there's any lock on that table by using `sp_who2`while updating? Try to query that table by using `with (nolock)` if it's possible.

Comment: @Rubik  The issue fixed itself. Now I am able to update with out any problem. Don't know what happened.

Comment: @Rubik really thanks for helping out. Actually the issue was there was a scheduled maintenance and one of the process failed and that was causing the problem. It is solved now.